# C4700: uninitialized local variable 'tuitionCost'

Tags: c++, function, initialization

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double tuitionCalc(int sumCreditHoursTaken);    //function prototype

    double tuitionCost;
    double creditHours;
    int numCourses;
    int count;
    int sumCreditHoursTaken = 0;

    cout << "       This program calculates a students total number of\n\n";
    cout << "       credit hours and tuition for a given semester.\n\n\n";

    cout << "Please enter the amount of courses you will be taking this semester: ";
    cin >> numCourses;

    for (count = 1; count <= numCourses; count++)   //for loop to find the total credit hours taken
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter the number of credit hours for class " << count << ": ";
        cin >> creditHours;
        sumCreditHoursTaken += creditHours;
    }

    cout << "\n\nYour total number of credit hours taken is: " << sumCreditHoursTaken << "\n\n";
    cout << "Your total tuition will be: $" << tuitionCalc(tuitionCost) << "\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It says the problem is occurring above where i try to call the function `tuitionCalc()`.

Here's the function I'm trying to call:

```
double tuitionCalc(int sumCreditHoursTaken)
{
    double tuitionCost = 0;                                                                         
    double costCreditHour = 147.00;
    double maintFeeAddOn = 29.33;
    int maxHoursFullTuition = 12;

    if (sumCreditHoursTaken <= maxHoursFullTuition)
        sumCreditHoursTaken * costCreditHour;
    else
        (maxHoursFullTuition * costCreditHour) + ((sumCreditHoursTaken - maxHoursFullTuition) * maintFeeAddOn);

    return tuitionCost;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
cout << "Your total tuition will be: $" << tuitionCalc(tuitionCost) << "\n\n";
```

you use the function `tuitionCalc` with an uninitialized argument `tuitionCost`. So the compiler tries to warn you. This is technically undefined behaviour. You need to make sure that whatever you pass to your function has a well defined value. In your case, because `tuitionCost` is not initialized, you pass whatever junk value happens to be stored at the memory location `&tuitionCost`. Remember that C++ **does not initialize variables to zero** for you. You need to initialize them manually if you pass them by value to a function. My guess is that you actually want to pass `sumCreditHoursTaken` (which you just compute above the function invocation) to your `tuitionCalc` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value of tuitionCost to the tuitionCalc method but you have not put anything in tuitionCost. Since the variable is declared locally it will have a random value in it. The compiler wants you to know that.